# Rewarded ads to temporarily remove ads android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, admob-rewardedvideoad

How do you make a rewarded video remove all ads in an app for a month for whoever watch the video in android studio? Or is this even possible?

Comment: Nope, we don't watch videos in **Android Studio** .

Comment: That's easy. In the `onRewarded` [method](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-video) write the time until which you want to hide ads into a `SharedPreferences`. Then, call the `loadAd` method only if the time has elapsed.